# Can anyone explain why does this solution to probability problem true?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

> Consider the general situation where a box contains $N$ balls, of which
>   $r$ are red and $N − r$ are white, and where balls are drawn without
>   replacement until n reds have been selected. We wish to find $p_x$ , the
>   probability that exactly $x$ balls are drawn.

The solution to this problem is given by the following (from the lecturer):

Now suppose that all $N$ balls are drawn, one by one, and the entire sequence of red and white balls is observed. Then $p_x = m_x / m$ , where $m$ is the total number of
arrangements (N-choose-r), and where $m_x$ is the number of arrangements with:

- $n-1$ red balls amongst the first $x − 1$ positions
- a red ball in position $x$
- $r−n$ red balls in the last $N−x$ positions.

Then $$p_x = {x-1 \choose n-1}{N-x \choose r-n}\div{N \choose r}$$

I just can't get what is the logic behind this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There are several steps in this solution. Which of them in particular did not make sense? Why not?

Comment: I don't see anything strange in the solution. Please state which step in particular seems strange to you. Then, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have 4 red balls and 6 white balls that we arrange in a line $RRRRWWWWWW$
So, $N = 10$ and $r = 4$ in this case.
The total number of arrangements:
$$\frac{10!}{4!6!} = \binom{10}{4} = \binom{N}{r}$$

Now, suppose n = 3 and x = 5
Then one possible arrangement is: $RRWWxRWWWW$ where x must be a red ball.

The number of arrangements of $RRWW$:
$$\frac{4!}{2!2!}=\frac{(x-1)!}{(n-1)!(x-1-(n-1))!} = \binom{x-1}{n-1}$$

The number of arrangements of $RWWWW$:
$$\frac{5!}{1!4!}=\frac{(10-5)!}{(4-3)!(4)!} = \binom{N-x}{r-n}$$

By the multiplication rule, the number of arrangements of $RRWWxRWWWW$ where x remains in the 5th position:

$$\binom{x-1}{n-1} \binom{N-x}{r-n}$$

Hence, $$p_x = \binom{x-1}{n-1} \binom{N-x}{r-n} / \binom{N}{r}$$

We normally think of $\binom{N}{r}$ as meaning selecting r objects from N objects.
However, in this case, we actually mean distinguishable arrangements.
Hopefully, that is why you were confused.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're confused by why the solution supposes that "all N balls are drawn".

It's a case of "completing a problem" to make it easier to solve without actually changing the answer.

If you think about it, the probability distribution of the two variables is the same:

1. Drawing till you hit n red balls and noting "x" which is the number of total balls drawn.
2. Drawing all N balls and then marking the point "x" at which you hit n red balls.

"#2" is just a "theoretical continuation" of "#1", it doesn't change the probability distribution of x. However, it does make $p_x$ way easier to calculate as we can use counting only and not have to deal with "probability of drawing a red" at a particular point. How many ways are there to have the nth red ball be at x?

1. You want n-1 red balls in the first x-1 positions. You can't do "n red balls in the first x positions" because we need the xth position to be a red ball for sure. That leads us to:
2. The $n^{th}$ ball should be red.
3. The rest of the balls should have r-n red balls to make a total of r.

Now, each particular order of balls that we draw is equally probable as each ball is drawn randomly. The total number of these drawings is $\binom{N}{r}$ the total number we want is determined by the 3 steps above $\binom{x-1}{n-1}\binom{N-x}{r-n}$.

The probability of a certain x being the point we hit "n" is the quotient of the two quantities.

Hope this helps!